# JavaScript: Use MediaRecorder to record streams from <video> but failed

Tags: javascript, video, mediaelement, multimedia

I'm trying to record parts of the video from a  tag, save it for later use. And I found this article: [Recording a media element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Recording_a_media_element), which described a method by first calling `stream = video.captureStream()`, then use `new MediaRecord(stream)` to get a recorder.

I've tested on some demos, the MediaRecorder works fine if `stream` is from user's device (such as microphone). However, when it comes to media element, my FireFox browser throws an exception: `MediaRecorder.start: The MediaStream's isolation properties disallow access from MediaRecorder`.

So any idea on how to deal with it?

Browser: Firefox

The page (including the js file) is stored at local.

The `src` attribute of `<video>` tag could either be a file from local storage or a url from Internet.

Code snippets:

```
let chunks = [];

let getCaptureStream = function () {
    let stream;
    const fps = 0;
    if (video.captureStream) {
      console.log("use captureStream");
      stream = video.captureStream(fps);
    } else if (video.mozCaptureStream) {
        console.log("use mozCaptureStream");
      stream = video.mozCaptureStream(fps);
    } else {
      console.error('Stream capture is not supported');
      stream = null;
    }
    return stream;
}

video.addEventListener('play', () => {
    let stream = getCaptureStream();
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.onstop = function() {
        const newVideo = document.createElement('video');
        newVideo.setAttribute('controls', '');
        newVideo.controls = true;
        const blob = new Blob(chunks);
        chunks = [];
        const videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob, { 'type' : 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' });
        newVideo.src = videoURL;
        document.body.appendChild(video);
    }
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
        chunks.push(e.data);
      }
      
    stopButton.onclick = function() {
        mediaRecorder.stop()
    }

    mediaRecorder.start(); // This is the line triggers exception.
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself.

When I turned to Chrome, it shows that a `CORS` issue limits me from even playing original video. So I guess it's because the secure strategy that preventing `MediaRecorder` from accessing `MediaStream`s. Therefore, I deployed the local files to a local server with instruction on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server).
After that, the `MediaRecorder` started working. Hope this will help someone in need.

But still, [the official document](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc-identity/#isolated-media-streams) doesn't seem to mention much about isolation properties of media elements. So any idea or further explanation is welcomed.